# Cancel button appears disabled when using presentViewController with UIImagePickerController in iOS 5

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

The Cancel button appears disabled and doesn't work when the image picker controller appears first, but as I move to the next view by selecting an album, the Cancel button becomes enabled and starts working fine.

What should I do to keep the Cancel button enabled and working all the time?

```
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
{
    NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imgPicker.sourceType];
    imgPicker.mediaTypes = sourceTypes;
    [self  presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)pick
```

Have you implement this function in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`?

[More reference](http://www.zimbio.com/iPhone/articles/1109/Picking+Images+iPhone+SDK+UIImagePickerController)